# MSSQL Start and End Time Grouped by 10 Minute, for Elapsed Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I need to take a start and end time that is already summarized in one row, and break it out into 10 minute window with the total time between.

Example of summary row.

```
    StartDowntime   |    EndDowntime    | ElapsedSecs
    =================================================
    1/17/2022 8:00  |    1/17/2022 9:05 |   3900
```

Desired output.

```
    Datetime        |    ElapsedSeconds  
    ===================================
    1/17/2022 8:00  |    600
    1/17/2022 8:10  |    600
    1/17/2022 8:20  |    600
    1/17/2022 8:30  |    600
    1/17/2022 8:40  |    600
    1/17/2022 8:50  |    600
    1/17/2022 9:00  |    300
    1/17/2022 9:10  |    0
    1/17/2022 9:20  |    0
```

**What I've tried.**

```
     ;with cte as 
        (select MIN(StartDowntime) as MinDate
              , MAX(StartDowntime) as MaxDate
              , convert(varchar(14),StartDowntime, 120) as StartDate
              , DATEPART(minute, StartDowntime) /15 as GroupID
              , avg(ElapsedSecs) as AvgAmount
         from tblOKDryerDowntime
          where StartDowntime >= '1/1/2022 7:00' and EndDowntime <= '1/17/2022 8:00'
         group by convert(varchar(14),StartDowntime, 120)
             , DATEPART(minute, StartDowntime) /15
             , Dryer,DowntimeCode)
             
    select dateadd(minute, 15*GroupID, CONVERT(datetime,StartDate+'00'))
             as [Start Date]
           , AvgAmount as [Average Amount]
      from cte
      order by [Start Date] desc
```

This gives me elapsed by start on the closest 15th minute.
But doesn't stop every 15 minutes.

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, we cannot make use of an image of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Stuck on where to start, as you would have to generate a table with 10 minute windows and join to it. Cannot conceptualize how to  associate the start and end, with only th esummary record

Comment: You would start by outer-joining with a numbers/tally table.

Comment: I edited the original. Would it be best to have a table with the 10 minute splits before hand.

Answer (score 1):

Discover the magic of a recursive CTE.

> ```
> ;WITH RCTE AS (
>     SELECT 
>       StartDowntime AS DownDatetime
>     , 600 AS ElapsedSeconds
>     , ElapsedSecs AS RemainingSeconds
>     , EndDowntime
>     , 1 AS Lvl
>     FROM tblOKDryerDowntime
>     
>     UNION ALL
>     
>     SELECT
>       DATEADD(second, ElapsedSeconds, DownDatetime)
>     , iif(RemainingSeconds > ElapsedSeconds, 600, RemainingSeconds) 
>     , iif(RemainingSeconds > ElapsedSeconds, RemainingSeconds - ElapsedSeconds, 0) 
>     , EndDowntime
>     , Lvl + 1
>     FROM RCTE
>     WHERE DownDatetime < EndDowntime
>       AND RemainingSeconds > 0
> )
> SELECT DownDatetime, ElapsedSeconds
> FROM RCTE
> ORDER BY DownDatetime;
> ```
>
> ```
> DownDatetime            | ElapsedSeconds
> :---------------------- | -------------:
> 2022-01-17 08:00:00.000 |            600
> 2022-01-17 08:10:00.000 |            600
> 2022-01-17 08:20:00.000 |            600
> 2022-01-17 08:30:00.000 |            600
> 2022-01-17 08:40:00.000 |            600
> 2022-01-17 08:50:00.000 |            600
> 2022-01-17 09:00:00.000 |            600
> 2022-01-17 09:10:00.000 |            300
> ```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=7dde20b28a620f0bd312b930b8f3a32d)*