# Summarising a table containing timestamps into 10-minute periods

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL-Server table called UserConnections that is structured like this:

| ID | User | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | 31-jan-2023 09:00:00 | 31-jan-2023 10:00:00 |
| 2 | Bob | 31-jan-2023 12:00:00 | 31-jan-2023 15:00:00 |
| 3 | Sally | 31-jan-2023 14:00:00 | 31-jan-2023 16:00:00 |

and I want to create a summary table for the previous day specifying the number of users connected during each 10-minute period. So it would look something like this

| Period Start | User Count |
| --- | --- |
| 31-jan-2023 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 31-jan-2023 00:10:00 | 0 |
| ... | ... |
| 31-jan-2023 09:00:00 | 1 |
| 31-jan-2023 09:10:00 | 1 |
| ... | ... |
| 31-jan-2023 12:00:00 | 1 |
| 31-jan-2023 12:10:00 | 1 |
| ... | ... |
| 31-jan-2023 14:00:00 | 2 |
| 31-jan-2023 14:10:00 | 2 |
| ... | ... |
| 31-jan-2023 15:00:00 | 1 |
| 31-jan-2023 15:10:00 | 1 |
| ... | ... |
| 31-jan-2023 16:00:00 | 0 |
| 31-jan-2023 16:10:00 | 0 |

So I need to get the start of each 10-minute period, and then count the number of connections where the [from] <= PeriodStart and [To] >= PeriodEnd

Given the start and end I can probably do the counting but I have no idea how to get the 10-minute periods (I am not experienced with complex SQL!).

I've looked at a few Date/Time functions but really don't know where to start.

I've also looked at this: [MSSQL Start and End Time Grouped by 10 Minute, for Elapsed Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70743039/mssql-start-and-end-time-grouped-by-10-minute-for-elapsed-time)
which looks similar but I'm having difficulty seeing how to adjust it for my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first trick here, which is really the basis for the entire solution, is to generate a list of all the 10 minute intervals for the day. To accomplish this I used a tally table. I keep one as a view on my system like this. I got my version from Jeff Moden who has a [great article](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1) on the topic.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
```

Next I need to create a table so I have something to work with on my machine.

```
declare @Something table
(
    ID int
    , [User] varchar(10)
    , [From] datetime
    , [To] datetime
)
insert @Something values
(1, 'Bob', '31-jan-2023 09:00:00', '31-jan-2023 10:00:00')
, (2, 'Bob', '31-jan-2023 12:00:00', '31-jan-2023 15:00:00')
, (3, 'Sally', '31-jan-2023 14:00:00', '31-jan-2023 16:00:00')
```

Now that I have the foundation setup the query is fairly straight forward.

```
with DateVals as --used a cte here so I don't have to write out the date math over and over. ;)
(
    select PeriodStart = dateadd(minute, (t.N - 1) * 10, convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate())))
    from cteTally t
    where t.N <= 144 --24 hours a day, 6 times an hour
)
select dv.PeriodStart
    , UserCount = count(s.[From])
from DateVals dv
left join @Something s on s.[From] <= dv.PeriodStart and s.[To] >  dv.PeriodStart
group by dv.PeriodStart
order by dv.PeriodStart
```

Comment: I had a look through that excellent article. Some of it went slightly over my head and there are aspects of this that I still don't fully understand but I have adapted your answer which was almost perfectly spot on already and it is working. 

Thank you so much!